# Android Studio 0.8.14 and 64 bit JDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I downloaded `Android Studio Beta v0.8.14 with the Android SDK for Windows` from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), however,  getting following error message:

[image: No JVM install 32bit JDK]

Now I do have JDK 1.7:

[image: JAVA_HOME]

Will it only work with 32 bits? If I download a 32 bit JDK I'll have to tinker with JAVA_HOME every time Android Studio is run?

Can somebody please help?

Comment: 0.8.14 is *not* the latest version. The most bleeding edge is 0.9.2

Comment: follow this guide http://vietpad.sourceforge.net/javaonwindows.html

Comment: @WarrenFaith my version is 0.8.6 but updates says i have the latest version! y so?

Comment: @HirakChhatbar that might depend on your update channel. To get the very latest use the canary channel. That is bleeding edge so be sure what you do...

Comment: I have Android Studio 0.8.14 64 bit with jdk 8 64 bit. So all right

Comment: I found it: There are two files, studio.exe and studio64.exe. Since I have 64 bit JDK, I should be running studio64.exe.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on this one too... until I noticed the android-studio\bin\studio**64**.exe executable.

64-bit Windows 8.1 (Version 6.3.9600), JDK 1.8.0_05

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Android Studio does work with a 64bit JDK. To fix this problem i suggest you first update to the latest version of Android Studio (as @WarrenFaith mentioned).

After that, if it still doesnt work, set an environment variable `ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK` to you JDK, and it should work.